# minipage alignment with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minipage

I want to have one `minipage` containing a `tikzpicture` and on its right another `minipage` with a `block`, and tried with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\tikzset{base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
 norm/.style={->, draw},
}
% -------------------------------------------------
    \node [base,text width=10cm] (one) {text in box};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\huge Legend}
       ...
      \end{block}
    \end{minipage}
```

However the two minipages become very distant (horizontally), as if the first minipage is aligned to the left margin and the second minipage is aligned to the right margin. Could anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: The `text width=10cm` is too large and is pushing the second `minipage` to the right (it produces an overfull `\hbox` warning alerting you about this).

Comment: You could put the tikzpicture inside an \rlap{...}.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet contains:

```
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}...
```

Thus, there is no horizontal space between them. The second `minipage` can be moved to the right by:

```
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}...
```

and putting both `minipage`s in a box:

```
\noindent
\hbox to \linewidth{%
  \begin{minipage}...
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}...
  \end{minipage}%
}\par
```

Or as last line of a paragraph:

```
\begin{minipage}...
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}...
\end{minipage}%
{\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}\par}
```

With a full MWE, it would have been easier to provide the best code.

Comment: ok thank you very much. tried but still have the separation, must be something else not related to minipage etc

Comment: @user3744868 Make a full example, that others can reproduce the problem.