# How to horizontally align a tikzpicture next a minipage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, minipage

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  \blindtext[0]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,baseline=1.5cm]
  \begin{axis} [
      view={0}{30},
      axis lines=none,]
      \addplot3 [ultra thick, blue, domain=3:7*pi, samples = 100, samples y=0] ({sin(deg(-x))}, {cos(deg(-x))}, {x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the tikzpicture is not centered horizontally in the left "0.4\linewidth-segment" (I call it 0.4\linewidth, because the minipage has width = 0.6\linewidth).

I use baseline to adjust vertical position of tikzpictures, every time manually choosing an appropriate value of the baseline. But how can move it horizontally? How can I draw my tikzpicture at the same distance from the text and the edge of the paper?

Comment: I found the below code works well --from the answer provided here --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262121/minipage-alignment-with-tikzpicture  -- please see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hbox to \linewidth{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
  \blindtext[0]
\end{minipage}\hspace{1in}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,]
    \begin{axis} [
        view={0}{30},
        axis lines=none,]
        \addplot3 [ultra thick, blue, domain=3:7*pi, samples = 100, samples y=0] ({sin(deg(-x))}, {cos(deg(-x))}, {x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Red lines indicate textwidth/margins.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\newlength{\mylength}       
\settoheight{\mylength}{S}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  \blindtext[0]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, baseline={([yshift=-\mylength]current bounding box.north)}]
  \begin{axis} [
      view={0}{30},
      axis lines=none,]
      \addplot3 [ultra thick, blue, domain=3:7*pi, samples = 100, samples y=0] ({sin(deg(-x))}, {cos(deg(-x))}, {x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```